# How to compare a string with the user's password?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to make an AppleScript program that asks the user to input their password and check if the text returned of the variable is equal to their real password. I am not trying to gain administrator privilege, just trying to retrieve the user's password and store it in a string. The reason why I bother to check the variable against the real user password is I don't want the user just enter something random. Are there any ways to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. I have looked into this quite a bit, and there is no way you can get the users pass. If you could, you could destroy their computer with a simple script. The "Keychain Application" keeps the passwords far away from any kind of script. Sorry to disapoint. :(

if you could, it would be like this:

`set realPassword to administrator password of (get system info)
set theirPassword to null
if realPassword is theirPassword then
say "yay"
else
say "nope"
end if`

Comment: em, thank! What i actually imagined is a function that takes a string as the argument, hash it, compare the hash, and return true or false. So it doesnt exist! Thanks anyways